# Pagination in django not pagination the posts by 6 posts per page

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-pagination

after writing the view for my pagination in django, the button works fine, meaning that they load new pagesz but the problem is that all the posts still remains in all the new pages and that is not what's expected.
views.py

```
def ElementLists(request):
    vectors = Vectors.objects.filter(status="published").order_by("?")
    paginator = Paginator(vectors, 6)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    vector_paginator = paginator.get_page(page_number)
```

elementlist.html

```
<li class="page-item">
   {% if vector_paginator.has_previous %}
      <a class="page-link" href="?page={{vector_paginator.previous_page_number}}" arialabel="Previous">
      <span class="ti-arrow-left">Previous</span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
   {% endif %}
</li>


<li class="page-item">
   {% if vector_paginator.has_next %}
       <a class="page-link" href="?page={{vector_paginator.next_page_number}}" aria-label="Next">
       <span class="ti-arrow-right">Load More</span>
       <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
       </a>
   {% endif %}
</li>
```

Comment: Since you render these random, pagination makes no sense, since it will each time retrieve items in a different order.

Comment: @willem-van-onsem please I'm a beginner in Django, please what should I do. Show me with code please 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I later got a fix for it
when looping thorught your posts in template, it should now be this

before

```
{% for post in posts %}
    ...code here
{% endfor %}
```

Now

```
{% for post in posts_paginator %}
    ...code here
{% endfor %}
```